# How to update documents in SolrCloud using MapReduceIndexerTool?

Tags: mapreduce, solrcloud

I am trying to index data to SolrCloud using [MapReduceindexerTool](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/search_mapreduceindexertool.html). I am successfully indexing using MapReduceindexerTool with option `--go-live`,which merging resulting index shards into a live SolrCloud cluster.But I find out it fails to update the documents when the document has already been in SolrCloud with the same unique document key. MapReduceindexerTool ignore all the duplicate documents, but I want it updated by the newest version of the very same document, using the same unique key.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [post](https://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/1456vfs4tx/update-existing-documents-using-mapreduceindexertool),and currently the tool can only insert documents and cannot update or delete existing SOLR documents.It seems like there is no plan to make it possible to updating/deleting the existing SOLR docs.